# Align textarea and button without button moving down when value is inserted

Tags: html, forms, alignment

I'm trying to align a text area and a button on the same line. I've successfully managed to do so, the code is in the fiddle below (though for some reason the fiddle won't align them).

Problem: Whenever I insert a value in the button, the button will go something like 30px downwards, still on the same line but just lower than the text area. This will only happen when a value is inserted within the button.

All the code is in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13qy0acp

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="messagebox">
<p id="headings"><textarea name="msg" style="height:40px;text-align:center" id="message" placeholder="Insert message"></textarea></p>
<p id="button"><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="submitChat()" id="innerbutton"></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#headings {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:70% !important;
margin-top:20px;
}
#message {
width:100%;
}
#button {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:8%;
margin-top:-30px !important;
border:solid black;
height:50px;
}
#innerbutton {
width:100%;
height:20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/13qy0acp/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to horizontally align two elements, use the `float` property and set a width that adds to no more than 100% of the width of the parent element.

example:

```
textarea {
  width:90%;
  float: left;
}
button {
  width:10%;
  float: left;
}
```